# SQL IN AND IN not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Okay, I've been at this logic going on weeks now, and I've yet to produce anything that will work.

**I'm using Wordpress, so this is saved as a string (which has PHP in it) before running through a query**

If you look at http://www.libertyguide.com/jobs you can see a filter.  What I want to do is use `AND` filtering between those three 'categories', but use `OR` filtering in between.

For example:

If I select `Academia,Law,Policy`,`Full-time,Part-time`,`Early-Career`, I expect to get a post that matches this filtering logic:

Post has `(academia OR law OR policy) AND (full-time OR part-time) AND (early-career)`.

So essentially I want to grab posts that match academia, law, or policy, and then filter out using full-time or part-time, and finally finish with checking if it has early-career.

Here's an example of the query that I run using the above example:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
WHERE 
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
        WHERE slug='academia' OR slug='law' OR slug='policy') AND
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
        WHERE slug='full-time' OR slug='part-time') AND
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
        WHERE slug='early-career') AND... //Rest of query/irrelevant
```

This hasn't produced any results.  I've also tried a query like this (first 5 lines are left out as they are the same as above example):

```
WHERE
    wp_term.slug IN ('academia','law','policy') AND
    wp_term.slug IN ('full-time','part-time') AND
    wp_term.slug IN ('early-career') AND ... //Rest of query
```

This returns results ONLY if one 'category' has selected items.  It doesn't work across categories.  I still think I have the query slightly wrong.  I've gotten a few solutions before (both of these are solutions that I believe have gotten me the closest), but they have loopholes.

Please don't have me use `HAVING COUNT` because I might as well make the whole thing an `AND` filter in that case, which isn't what I want.

ANY help will be greatly appreciated, and if it works, I wouldn't mind working out something to make up for the trouble.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the `$` and `->` denoting?  They are not normal SQL.  Are you embedding Perl or something into the mixture?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using PHP (I'm using WordPress). My question is updated to mention that I'm using it.  Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking just the WHERE clause, we can see some problems:

```
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
                                    WHERE slug='academia' OR slug='law' OR slug='policy')
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
                                    WHERE slug='full-time' OR slug='part-time')
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
                                    WHERE slug='early-career')
```

Here we have single column (`wp_term_taxonomy.term_id`) that has to be simultaneously the same as the term ID for one of Academia, Law or Policy (presumably 3 distinct values) and also the same as the term ID for one of Full-Time or Part-Time (presumably 2 distinct values, and different from each of the 3 previous values) and also the same as the term ID for Early-Career (one value, but distinct from each of the previous 5 values.  So, the single term ID has to be 3 different values at once, and it can't manage it.

You're likely to need to join with the `wp_term_taxonomy` table multiple times, using 3 different aliases.

```
WHERE wtt1.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
                        WHERE slug='academia' OR slug='law' OR slug='policy')
  AND wtt2.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
                        WHERE slug='full-time' OR slug='part-time')
  AND wtt3.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
                        WHERE slug='early-career')
```

where the 3 aliases I used are `wtt1`, `wtt2`, and `wtt3`.  They'd be listed in the JOIN conditions.

---

Let's look at the select list and the FROM clause

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
```

Now let's disentangle some of the PHP material, leaving behind regular SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts                   AS p
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta           AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
```

You probably do not want any left joins in here; you don't want to see posts that do not match the criteria, but using LEFT JOIN will mean that many posts get selected in this part (though all the rows are later discarded by the broken WHERE condition already discussed).

A single post may have multiple term relationship entries.  We want a post that has at least three term relationship entries: one for the Academia/Law/Policy trio, one for the Full-Time/Part-Time duo, and also Early-Career.

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts    AS p
  JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.Post_ID
  JOIN (SELECT t1.Object_ID
          FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug IN ('academia', 'law', 'policy')
       ) AS t1 ON p.ID = t1.Object_ID
  JOIN (SELECT t1.Object_ID
          FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug IN ('full-time', 'part-time')
       ) AS t2 ON p.ID = t2.Object_ID
  JOIN (SELECT t1.Object_ID
          FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug = 'early-career')
       ) AS t3 ON p.ID = t3.Object_ID
```

I think that may do the trick — but it's getting late and I could be completely off the wall.  It certainly isn't a simple query as written.

---

Assuming I got the basic SQL right, you simply have to replace the table names with the PHP notation for them:

```
SELECT *
  FROM $wpdb->posts    AS p
  JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.Post_ID
  JOIN (SELECT t1.Object_ID
          FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN $wpdb->terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug IN ('academia', 'law', 'policy')
       ) AS t1 ON p.ID = t1.Object_ID
  JOIN (SELECT t1.Object_ID
          FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN $wpdb->terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug IN ('full-time', 'part-time')
       ) AS t2 ON p.ID = t2.Object_ID
  JOIN (SELECT t1.Object_ID
          FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN $wpdb->terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug = 'early-career')
       ) AS t3 ON p.ID = t3.Object_ID
```

You've not said which DBMS is in use, but it is likely MySQL.  If you were using Oracle, you'd have to leave the AS's out of the table aliases.  Standard SQL and most other SQL DBMS are fine with the AS for the table alias.  Note how the use of the `$wpdb->` notation is limited by the use of the table aliases; it makes the code easier to read (though it is still not an easy read).

---

#### Bug Fixing and Problem Solving

Untested code usually has bugs; this is no different from any other untested code.

The first test step was to run the sub-queries in the FROM clause in individually.  That immediately showed that they should not be referencing `t1.Object_ID`; it should be `tr.Object_ID` in each case.  There was also an extraneous right parenthesis after 'early-career'.  These mistakes were easily spotted once I had a test database against which to run the (sub)queries.

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts    AS p
  JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.Post_ID
  JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID
          FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug IN ('academia', 'law', 'policy')
       ) AS t1 ON p.ID = t1.Object_ID
  JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID
          FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug IN ('full-time', 'part-time')
       ) AS t2 ON p.ID = t2.Object_ID
  JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID
          FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
          JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
         WHERE tm.slug = 'early-career'
       ) AS t3 ON p.ID = t3.Object_ID
```

With those fixes in place, the query ran and generated rows of data.  You might legitimately decide you want the slugs from the three sub-queries in the results.  You'd change the sub-queries to return `tr.Object_ID, tm.slug`.  For example, this variant of the query:

```
SELECT p.ID, t1.slug_1, t2.slug_2, t3.slug_3, pm.meta_key
      FROM wp_posts    AS p
      JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.Post_ID
      JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID, tm.slug AS slug_1
              FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
              JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
             WHERE tm.slug IN ('academia', 'law', 'policy')
           ) AS t1 ON p.ID = t1.Object_ID
      JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID, tm.slug AS slug_2
              FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
              JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
             WHERE tm.slug IN ('full-time', 'part-time')
           ) AS t2 ON p.ID = t2.Object_ID
      JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID, tm.slug AS slug_3
              FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
              JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
             WHERE tm.slug = 'early-career'
           ) AS t3 ON p.ID = t3.Object_ID;
```

produced the following result on some test data:

```
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  date_legible
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  date_timestamp
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  longitude
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  date_normal
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  url
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  _su_rich_snippet_type
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  _edit_last
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  expiration-date
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  organization
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  latitude
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  location
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  _edit_lock
```

This shows that there is at least one post (ID = 1575) that has the three traits you require, but it also shows that you're going to have to deal with the PostMeta data more cleverly.  The result rather suggests that the PostMeta is an EAV ([Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) model.  This is going to require careful handling to pull useful information (such as latitude and longitude) for the given posting.  Indeed, you are going to need one (possibly outer) join for each separate meta-attribute that you want to examine.

For example, to collect the latitude and longitude, if available, for the post, you'd need to write:

```
SELECT p.ID, t1.slug_1, t2.slug_2, t3.slug_3, p1.latitude, p2.longitude
      FROM wp_posts    AS p
      LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT Post_ID, Meta_Key AS m1_key, Meta_Value AS latitude
              FROM wp_postmeta
             WHERE Meta_Key = 'latitude'
           ) AS p1 ON p.ID = p1.Post_ID
      LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT Post_ID, Meta_Key AS m2_key, Meta_Value AS longitude
              FROM wp_postmeta
             WHERE Meta_Key = 'longitude'
           ) AS p2 ON p.ID = p2.Post_ID
      JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID, tm.slug AS slug_1
              FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
              JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
             WHERE tm.slug IN ('academia', 'law', 'policy')
           ) AS t1 ON p.ID = t1.Object_ID
      JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID, tm.slug AS slug_2
              FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
              JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
             WHERE tm.slug IN ('full-time', 'part-time')
           ) AS t2 ON p.ID = t2.Object_ID
      JOIN (SELECT tr.Object_ID, tm.slug AS slug_3
              FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
              JOIN wp_term_taxonomy      AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              JOIN wp_terms              AS tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id
             WHERE tm.slug = 'early-career'
           ) AS t3 ON p.ID = t3.Object_ID;
```

Which produces:

```
1575  policy  full-time  early-career  -33.8210366  151.1887557
```

Etcetera.

Comment: I see what you're doing there.  That should work.  I'm currently trying to implement the other answer.  I'll post back with what I find.  Thanks!

Comment: I changed my code to reflect your answer, but even with the alias's, it will still only work with one 'category' selected.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extensive update! I'll try to implement this! Thanks!

Comment: *sigh* I wish I was this advanced.  I'll try my best at getting this to work, but I think this is a little advanced for me.  Thanks for the help, I'm sure it'd work if I knew how to implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to do a subquery (not IN or EXISTS) using previous results? Couldn't I just run my results through a query 3 times (I know it's highly inefficient) checking against one of the three categories each time?

Comment: So I leave out my WHERE stuff from the `SELECT *` query?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10770/discussion-between-josh-allen-and-jonathan-leffler)

Answer (score 0):

Change your IN to EXISTS; try it out — you will get your result.

```
WHERE 
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id exists (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
        WHERE slug='academia' OR slug='law' OR slug='policy') AND
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id exists(SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
        WHERE slug='full-time' OR slug='part-time') AND
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id exists (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
        WHERE slug='early-career') AND... //Rest of query/irrelevant
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please do not use SMS abbreviations on SO.  Please do use the 'code' button (the `{}` above the edit box) to indent the selected text as code.  I've fixed it for you this time since you're new here.  Please don't do it again.

Comment: I'm trying this and I'll report back.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I altered my code and now it returns absolutely nothing.  If I keep it `IN`, I can at least get it to work using one 'category'.  When changing it to `EXISTS`, no results are found no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR:

```
wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
    WHERE slug='academia' OR slug='law' OR slug='policy') 

OR wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
    WHERE slug='full-time' OR slug='part-time') 

OR wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
    WHERE slug='early-career') AND... //Rest of query/irrelevan
```

Analyzing your query, shouldn't it be merely:

```
wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
    WHERE slug='academia' OR slug='law' OR slug='policy'
       OR slug='full-time' OR slug='part-time'
       OR slug='early-career')
```

Comment: Not quite.  That's the way the filter is now.  It's currently a global `OR` filter.  However, I want to make sure posts that are returned have at least one term from each of my filters 'categories'.

Comment: Let's say wp_term_taxonomy.term_id is 1.  and acadamia,law,policy,full-time,part-time's wp_terms.term_id are 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. The first condition will result to `True`, the second condition(AND) will never be True, none on 4,5 matches the taxonomy.term_id's value of. I think AND is not the right condition here

Comment: That makes sense to me now. I'm looking into Jonathan Leffler's answer now, as he addresses that correctly.  I see now that what I'm doing is trying to analyze one term across multiple statements, which could never be true.

Comment: Ok, no need for me to ponder about it anymore. Jonathan Leffler has same thoughts http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407658/11432 And you understood the problem already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407549/sql-in-and-in-not-working/10407705#comment13426394_10407658

Comment: True, it could never be true :-) A column cannot have multiple values